# Running Ajax .POST on Local Host server and it always fails?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I've been working on getting the .POST method for AJAX to run for a local host program.

The idea is that a user clicks on a row in a table, the col[0] of that row, which corresponds to a ID, gets saved and sent to database to retrieve the rest of the data associated with that ID. The clicking works, the ID does get saved as 'alias', but the POST always fails.

I've tried different datatypes, JSON.stringifying the data, adding content-type, and nothing has worked. I have a feeling something is wrong with my URL, but I'm just not familiar enough with this stuff to know what. Before, I was using `'http://localhost:5000/GetTestPoint.php'` but that threw an invalid syntax error, so I used the IP address instead. This got rid of the syntax error, but POST still fails and I think I would have to change the IP address every time the program is run on a different computer, so I don't think that is a long term solution either. Also as a side note we don't have internet access on the work pcs so any solutions that would require that are not possible, unless the only solution is to add another package or something.

A few things to note:

alias looks like this :   `420060300100`

Also, for the `console.log` results:
jqXHR.status returns 0.

`textStatus` returns error.

and `errorThrown` returns

```
{"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"filURL":"http://localhost:5000/TestPoints","lineNumber":37832, "columnNumber":21}}
```

To be honest I have no clue what the `errorThrown` response means, it just seems to be backend code? The line # is the line of `console.log(errorThrown)` but that's about the extent of I understand from it.

So my main questions are, would there be any reason that .POST doesn't work for localhost? Is my syntax correct? Is there something wrong with my url? Any help would be appreciated!!

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "10.20.100.91:5000/TestPoint.php",
   data: alias,
   dataType: 'text'
 })
.done(function() {
   alert("success"); })

.fail(function( jqXHR, TextStatus, errorThrown ){
 
alert("failed");
 console.log(jqXHR.status);
 console.log(textStatus);
 console.log(errorThrown);
})
```

GetTestPoints.php

```
<?
echo $_POST["alias];
?>
```

There's barely anything in there, I just wanted to confirm .POST would work before I added more code to it.

Comment: Do you miss a double quote in the alias? echo $_POST["alias];

Comment: Just a typo in the post, on the actual php file its ["alias"]

Comment: You also miss a coma in the end of ```url: "10.20.100.91:5000/TestPoint.php"```

Comment: Then you should do that proofreading before posting code here.

Comment: fair enough! Is there anything else I missed?